# Django in Docker Container not working with Selenium Grid 4

Tags: python, django, docker, selenium, selenium-grid

I recently started trying to containerize a django app. I've been trying to get the tests work for a few days with no luck. I have no experience with Selenium Grid but it seems like the way to work with Django in a docker container, especially if I need to be able to view whats happening.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "
        npm run build
        && python manage.py migrate
        && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

    volumes:
      - ./:/myapp
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: myapp-container
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 171.20.0.3
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 171.20.0.4

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1
    container_name: chrome-worker
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 171.20.0.8


networks:
    mynetwork:
      ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 171.20.0.0/24
            gateway: 171.20.0.1
```

Within my code it should just be a matter of changing `context.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)` to below:

```py
# environment.py - for Behave BDD testing

os.environ['DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS'] = 'localhost:8000'

def before_all(context):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=3840,2160")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    # context.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    context.selenium = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444', options=chrome_options)
    context.selenium.implicitly_wait(1)
    TransactionTestCase.serialized_rollback = True
```

However this results in this error:

```sh
HOOK-ERROR in before_all: MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb9ddfe15b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I update the command_executer to use the service hostname like the following:

```py
   context.selenium = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444', options=chrome_options)
```

This seems like progress and the tests start running but I get a different connection error for each individual test:

```sh
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

Additionally there now seems to be activity from the selenium-hub and chrome service

```
selenium-hub     | 16:07:16.940 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session created by the distributor. Id: 444dbca185db76e7e8780c98680b7859, Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 96.0.4664.45, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab46..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.2RTzs7}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:40633}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: ANY, proxy: {}, se:cdp: ws://171.20.0.8:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 96.0.4664.45, se:vnc: ws://171.20.0.8:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://171.20.0.8:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
chrome-worker    | 16:07:28.510 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "ae4768e55f596539cf20032361104584","eventTime": 1637770048509670200,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute","http.host": "171.20.0.4:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "41","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession\u002f444dbca185db76e7e8780c98680b7859\u002furl","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f3.141.0 (python linux)"}}
chrome-worker    | 
chrome-worker    | 16:07:51.014 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$0] - {"traceId": "338e4e8e48d62681ed1cb1e729d490d6","eventTime": 1637770071013768000,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute","http.host": "171.20.0.4:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "41","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession\u002f444dbca185db76e7e8780c98680b7859\u002furl","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f3.141.0 (python linux)"}}
```

I've tried removing the custom network which I added to deal with another issue, but that didn't help. I've also tried using specific IP addresses. When I try connecting to the other containers from the `myapp` container with `curl -I http://selenium-hub/4444`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
content-length: 0
Location: /ui/index.html
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Edit: Some additional context:

I'm using the [Behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) test framework along with the behave-django package. Setup and teardown is in an environment.py file which is what is shown above. All tests located in a `features` module and using docker I start with `docker exec -it myapp-container ./manage.py behave ./myapp/features/account.feature`.  This is completely functional outside of docker with regular webdriver. I added a line above showing where `DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS` environment variable is set. Seems like that's been important in other issues with getting this to work. I've tried setting that as the django service hostname - `myapp` as well as the assigned ip address. The behave-django library spins up a test server using [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase)

Comment: whats a "django app"? It that a service you're trying to test with Selenium?

Comment: Django is a python web framework. Yes I'm trying to move it to docker and continue testing with selenium. Grid seems a better option with docker however. It was already setup with selenium webdriver so I just had to change the one line I mentioned above.

Comment: I can only see your app and selenium containers on docker-compose file. But there is no container with tests. How do you run them?

Comment: I added a bit more to my question but all tests are within a `features` module within the app.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact issue today while dockerizing an app which uses behave-django and Selenium Grid.

The core issue is that the Selenium/Firefox container needs to use the 'myapp' host instead of 'localhost'.

I monkey patched the `LiveServerTestCase` class in my `environment.py` like this:

```
import os
from django.test.testcases import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "backend.settings"


def before_all(context):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    if os.path.exists("/.dockerenv"):
        LiveServerTestCase.host = "myapp"
        context.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor="http://firefox:4444/wd/hub",
            desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities(),
        )
    else:
        # needs geckodriver on system $PATH to control local firefox
        context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)


def after_all(context):
    context.driver.quit()
```

Do **NOT** override `LiveServerTestCase`'s `port` attribute. Each test instantiates a new server on a random port. I didn't know this and spent ages wondering why my first test would pass but the second always got an 'Address in use' error.

When you use `context.get_url()` in your behave steps, the url will be updated with the 'myapp' host and the random port for that test. Eg. `http://myapp:378936`.

Further note the if-else logic which checks if I'm in a Docker environment. This way, I don't lost the ability to run the project in the usual way on my local machine.

Comment: A big thank you.  I've spent a day trying to find I need to add `LiveServerTestCase.host = "myapp"` in my LiveServerTestCase tests!